# How to configure Domain-based forwarding on RT-AC3200 router?

Tags: networking, port-forwarding

I hope this is the correct community to ask this, really not sure. Also bear with me as I have only very basic networking skills.

My home network has a ASUS RT-AC3200 router. My main desktop in this network is a W10 machine on which I run two Linux VMs, using VMWare Workstation.

Both VMs have a local IP, let's say:

```
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
```

I'd like to access both VMs from outside my network, by domain:

```
abc.com -> 192.168.1.1
def.com -> 192.168.1.2
```

For this I use port forwarding in the router's admin panel. Unfortunately, I can only assign one IP per port, there's no way to distinguish traffic over the same port (HTTP) by domain. So I can achieve the above for one domain, but not two.

I know that I could run HTTP on one of the VMs on a different port (8080), yet I wonder if its possible to achieve my original goal of having some type of domain based routing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Not at all*. Port forwarding is something that happens based on network layer 3/4 information (so, IP + TCP/UDP ports). Domains do not exist at these layers.

What you want is an HTTP reverse proxy. It knows about HTTP and can look at the request’s `Host` header. Theoretically you could run it on your router.

Comment: Understood, I was above all hoping the router would have some option like this built-in.